# Efficient string splitting

Tags: c#

I'm not very expert in c#. I'm looking for a way to split string in an efficent way.
I've a byte[64] array coming from a client request to a server.
I convert it into a sting with the command

```
string d=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)
```

After this conversion d is a 64 long string. In that string I've a part dedicated to the type of command that the client is requesting to the server and a username like this:
"!command username". I want to split the part after !command, but not with the simple use of Split, because using Split will produce a 56 long string (username+ a lot of \0 characters).
I want only to get the username without all those \0 characters. Is there anyway to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a problem made for Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Try `d.Split(' ')[1].Trim((char)0);`